# HTML5/JavaScript: how to display swf flash files in windows-store-apps?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps

I was developing an app on the platform of `HTML5/JavaScript` for `Windows Store App`.

Now, I need to display my `swf flash file` file in the app.

But i dunno how to display it. Does anyone know how to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. From [the Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465143.aspx):

> WWAHost.exe cannot host Adobe Flash Player objects. If a Flash component is essential to your web app, you must port the Flash object to HTML/CSS and JavaScript. HTML5 and the Windows Runtime provide some of the lower-level OS and user interface (UI) functionality you need to accomplish this.

Comment: then how to display `swf flash files` in `windows store apps`. help me please

Comment: @user2655873 — Are you seriously asking "If I can't do X, how can I do X?". You **can't**. Simple as that.